# copy attribute value to html

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm new to xslt and xpath.  I have an xml document I'm trying to convert to html.  That part is easy.  I'm having trouble trying to get text out of the attributes.  I can get the element values, but not the attribute values.

I've been googling and reading a few books, but am growing weary of not seeing what I'm looking for, or not knowing what I'm seeing is what I want.

Here is the xml:

```
<INDV>
  <TYP_COD value="A">FULL III</TYP_COD>
  <REL_IDN value=""/>
  <NCP_COD value=""/>
  <III_COD value="S">SINGLE STATE</III_COD>
</INDV>
```

here is the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
   <xsl:template match="/INDV">
       <html>
         <body>
           <h1>
               Test: <xsl:value-of select="child::value"/>
           </h1>
         </body>
       </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to get the "A" and also the "FULL III" from TYP_COD) The only thing I've been able to get is the "FULL III".

Comment: Use `<xsl:value-of select="TYP_COD"/>` to get ""FULL III". Use `<xsl:value-of select="TYP_COD/@value"/>` to get "A". -- Note that `child::` can be omitted: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev

Comment: If you could put that in as a potential answer, I'll flag it as the accepted answer.  Thank you!!!

Comment: Well, it's rather trivial. Best to delete this question altogether.

Comment: I can make it more challenging :-)  What if there are several like the above only with different names (different than TYP_COD) but all with the "value" attribute... How would I shove those into an html table?

Comment: You could use `<xsl:for-each select="*/@value">`.

Comment: You're my new best friend!